# Add range of IPs to a firewalld zone

Tags: ipv4, firewalld

I'm struggling with the syntax for the following.

If I want to add a single IP to a zone, I do this:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=drop --add-source=134.119.193.63
```

But, how would I add `134.119.xxx.xxx`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify IP address ranges by CIDR.

```
--add-source=134.119.0.0/16
```

Comment: Thanks, partly understand how that works. I'm not actually familiar with subnets and CIDR, its a gap in my knowledge. I assume that because each block is 8 bits, setting it to `/16` and the last two blocks to `.0.0` like that, means its basically a wildcard?

Comment: @Pickledegg That's about right. You should learn CIDR as soon as possible; it's something you'll need frequently in IT. Our own [canonical Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/49765/126632) might make a good starting point.